# set mutltiple hashes in redis

Tags: php, redis

I'm using the following library: [predis php library](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-redis-in-php). Here's the direct github [predis github code](https://github.com/nrk/predis)

In my code, I'm doing the following:

```
$st=mysqli_query($dbh,"select somethoing from something");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($st)){
  $redis->hmset("us-states-data-hash",$row);
}
```

Unfortunately, the ending result of storing the data in redis is only the last record from the sql query.

How do I get all of the rows into redis with a hash tag of `us-states-data-hash`

Answer (score 0):

[The `HMSET` Redis command](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) requires a key (`us-states-data-hash` in your example) and pairs of field names and values.

While Predis' documentation is still being revised, its tests appear robust. Of specific interest is the [HashSetMultipleTest.php](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.1/tests/Predis/Command/HashSetMultipleTest.php) file that shows you how to use `hmset`.

Your code is passing an associative array to `hmset`, whereas it looks like you need to splat it, i.e.:

```
$redis->hmset("us-states-data-hash", ...$row);
```